# Gitlab integration with Hashicorp Vault

Tags: gitlab, hashicorp-vault

I have integrated my self hosted Gitlab with Hashicorp vault. I have followed the steps here https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/examples/authenticating-with-hashicorp-vault/ and tried to run the pipeline.

I am receiving the certificate error while running the pipeline.

```
Error writing data to auth/jwt/login: Put "https://vault.systems:8200/v1/auth/jwt/login": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

My .gitlab yml file -

```
Vault Client:
  image:
    name: vault:latest
    entrypoint:
        - '/usr/bin/env'
        - 'PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'
  before_script:

  script:
    - export VAULT_ADDR=https:/vault.systems:8200/
    - export VAULT_TOKEN="$(vault write -field=token auth/jwt/login role=staging jwt=$CI_JOB_JWT)"
    - export PASSWORD="$(vault kv get -field=password kv/project/staging/db)"
    - echo $PASSWORD
```

If i use `-tls-skip-verify` flag then it works fine.

Do i need to place the self signed server certificate somewhere on the vault server or gitlab server?
Please let me know if anyone has any ideas on this one?

Answer (score 2):

The containers that are managed by the docker/kube executor must be configured to trust the self-signed cert(s). You can edit the `config.toml` for your runner to mount in the trusted certs/CA roots to GitLab CI job containers

For example, on Linux-based docker executors:

```
  [[runners]]
   name = "docker"
   url = "https://example.com/"
   token = "TOKEN"
   executor = "docker"

   [runners.docker]
     image = "ubuntu:latest"

     # Add path to your ca.crt file in the volumes list
     volumes = ["/cache", "/path/to-ca-cert-dir/ca.crt:/etc/gitlab-runner/certs/ca.crt:ro"]
```

See the [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/tls-self-signed.html#trusting-tls-certificates-for-docker-and-kubernetes-executors) for more info.

Comment: hi, thanks for your response. So this is how I am running my gitlab runner container
```docker run -d --name gitlab-runner --restart always -v /srv/gitlab-runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner -v /app/log/docker-rootless/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest``` and I have placed my server certificate```vault.systems.crt``` using  volume but that has still not worked. I think that is what you were referring to right?
Is there anything else i am missing?

Comment: @mikitaagrawal You need to not only mount the cert into the runner itself, but also make the changes in the  `config.toml` so that containers that the runner creates also have the certificates mounted in when jobs are run. After all, jobs don't run in the _runner_ container, they run in a separate container.

Comment: How and where do i put the certificates then? Is it just the ```vault.systems.crt``` which i need to place. If you could help me with the steps it would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by using this variable `VAULT_CACERT` in my gitlab.yml file :
`- export VAULT_CACERT=/etc/gitlab-runner/certs/ca.crt`. The certificate path here is the path of the mounted container which we specify during the start of container.

Posting this so if anyone is looking for it, this is the solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Error writing data to auth/jwt/login: Put "https://vault.systems:8200/v1/auth/jwt/login": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

The error you're receiving is being returned from *Vault*, so it's Vault that you need to get to accept that certificate. There's a decent note on how to do it in [the Deployment Guide](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/vault/deployment-guide#listener-stanza). (I used to work for HashiCorp Vault so I knew where to dig it up.)

Comment: If OP can circumvent the problem with the client-side flag `-tls-skip-verify` that would indicate to me this error actually comes from the vault CLI, not the vault server. So I'm confused how the server deployment configuration comes into play here. Does Vault not trust its own configured certificate and how does the client tell Vault to skip this verification?

Answer (score 0):

You can use -tls-skip-verify in your vault command `vault kv get -tls-skip-verify -field=password kv/project/staging/db` , or if you have vault's ca-cert you have to export CA CERT path by setting VAULT_CACERT to the right path .